# Error Warning: CompontMounts renamed.. ERROR

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting this warning with my application and I don't know how to fix it. I have used `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` as it recommends but still, the error keeps showing up and it is hard to debug. Here is the error below:

```
react-dom.development.js:88 Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. 

* Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.
* Rename componentWillMount to UNSAFE_componentWillMount to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: BrowserRouter, Route, Router, Switchnull
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:88
warn @ react-dom.development.js:51
ReactStrictModeWarnings.flushPendingUnsafeLifecycleWarnings @ react-dom.development.js:11371
flushRenderPhaseStrictModeWarningsInDEV @ react-dom.development.js:23112
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:22396
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11039
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22381
finishSyncRender @ react-dom.development.js:21807
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:21793
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21188
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24373
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:24758
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:21903
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24757
render @ react-dom.development.js:24840
(anonymous) @ app.js:22
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 13223e8494d0327abec5:18
(anonymous) @ worker-page-message.js:48
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 13223e8494d0327abec5:18
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 13223e8494d0327abec5:61
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 13223e8494d0327abec5:62
react-dom.development.js:88 Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.

* Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
* If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps.
* Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: Connect(ExpenseList), Connect(ExpenseListFilters), Connect(ExpensesSummary), DateInput, Provider, Route, Router, Switchnull
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:88
warn @ react-dom.development.js:51
ReactStrictModeWarnings.flushPendingUnsafeLifecycleWarnings @ react-dom.development.js:11377
flushRenderPhaseStrictModeWarningsInDEV @ react-dom.development.js:23112
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:22396
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11039
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22381
finishSyncRender @ react-dom.development.js:21807
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:21793
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21188
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24373
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:24758
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:21903
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24757
render @ react-dom.development.js:24840
(anonymous) @ app.js:22
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 13223e8494d0327abec5:18
(anonymous) @ worker-page-message.js:48
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 13223e8494d0327abec5:18
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 13223e8494d0327abec5:61
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 13223e8494d0327abec5:62
react-dom.development.js:88 Warning: componentWillUpdate has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. 

* Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
* Rename componentWillUpdate to UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: Connect(ExpenseList), Connect(ExpenseListFilters), Connect(ExpensesSummary)null
```

When I run that command this is the result.

```
-MacBook-Pro:expensify-app stephenbilham$ npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles
⸨⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⸩ ⠧ rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session a57694d454f99861
npx: installed 507 in 24.617s
? On which files or directory should the codemods be applied? .
? Which dialect of JavaScript do you use? JavaScript
Executing command: jscodeshift --verbose=2 --ignore-pattern=**/node_modules/** --parser babel --extensions=jsx,js --transform /Users/stephenbilham/.npm/_npx/30846/lib/node_modules/react-codemod/transforms/rename-unsafe-lifecycles.js .
Processing 49 files...
Spawning 3 workers...
Sending 17 files to free worker...
Sending 17 files to free worker...
Sending 15 files to free worker...
 SKIP public/src/components/ExpenseListFilters.js
 SKIP public/src/app.js
 SKIP public/src/components/ExpensesSummary.js
 SKIP public/src/components/Header.js
 SKIP public/src/components/HelpPage.js
 SKIP public/src/components/NoPage.js
 SKIP webpack.config.js
 SKIP public/src/actions/expenses.js
 SKIP public/src/reducers/expenses.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/__mocks__/moment.js
 SKIP public/src/actions/filters.js
 SKIP public/src/reducers/filters.js
 SKIP public/src/routers/AppRouter.js
 SKIP server/server.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/components/ExpenseListFilters.test.js
 SKIP public/src/firebase/firebase.js
 SKIP public/src/components/ExpenseListItem.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/components/ExpenseList.test.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/components/ExpensesSummary.test.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/components/Header.test.js
 SKIP public/src/playground/hoc.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/actions/expenses.test.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/components/ExpenseListItem.test.js
 SKIP public/src/playground/destructuring.js
 SKIP public/src/selectors/expenses.js
 SKIP public/src/store/configureStore.js
 SKIP public/src/selectors/expenses-total.js
 SKIP public/src/playground/redux101.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/components/AddExpensePage.test.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/setupTests.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/components/Dashboard.test.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/components/NoPage.test.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/components/EditExpense.test.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/reducers/expenses.test.js
 SKIP public/src/playground/redux-expensify.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/reducers/filters.test.js
 SKIP public/src/components/Dashboard.js
 SKIP public/src/components/AddExpensePage.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/components/ExpenseForm.test.js
 SKIP public/src/components/EditExpense.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/selectors/expenses.test.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/actions/filters.test.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/selectors/expenses-total.test.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/fixtures/expenses.js
 SKIP public/src/tests/fixtures/filters.js
 SKIP public/src/components/ExpenseForm.js
 SKIP public/src/components/ExpenseList.js
 SKIP public/bundle.js
 SKIP public/dist/bundle.js
All done.
Results:
0 errors
0 unmodified
49 skipped
0 ok
```

Comment: Have you tried to use componentDidMount istead of componentWillMount ?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't work and the npx line ran and changed everything to UNSAFE_Component and still got the error.

Comment: According to https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6481 this issue was solved in version 4.4+ of react-router-dom. Which version are you usinge?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed, this seems to be a known bug when using Strict Mode, and it's fixed updating your version of React-Router to 4.4